# How to detect if an argument was passed to the script?

Tags: bash

I am a novice at shell scripting. I have written a script that takes zero or more options and an optional path parameter. I want to use the current directory if a path parameter is not set.

This is the argument parsing section of the script:

```
OPTIONS=$(getopt -o dhlv -l drop-databases,help,learner-portal,verifier-portal -- "$@")

if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
  echo "getopt error"
  exit 1
fi

eval set -- $OPTIONS

while true; do 
  case "$1" in
    -d|--drop-databases)  RESETDB=1
                          ;;
    -h|--help)            echo "$usage"
                          exit
                          ;;
    -l|--learner-portal)  LERPOR=1
                          ;;
    -v|--verifier-portal) VERPOR=1
                          ;;
    --)                   shift
                          break;;
    *)                    echo -e "\e[31munknown option: $1\e[0m"
                          echo "$usage"
                          exit 1
                          ;;
  esac
  shift
done

# Set directory of module
if [[ -n $BASH_ARGV ]]
then
  MOD_DIR=$(readlink -f $BASH_ARGV)
fi

if [[ -n $MOD_DIR ]]
then
  cd $MOD_DIR
fi
```

The script works as intended when called without and arguments, or when called with both options and a path.

However, when I run the script and only specify options, I get an error from readlink like so

```
$ rebuild_module -dv
readlink: invalid option -- 'd'
Try 'readlink --help' for more information.
```

Obviously, it's parsing the options wrong, but I'm not sure how to detect that I haven't passed a path, and therefore avoid calling readlink. How can I go about correcting this behaviour?

Comment: -dv works fine. Any combination of flags works.

Comment: Thanks evan, I didn't look closely enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do `[ $# -ne 0 ]` instead of `[[ -n $BASH_ARGV ]]`. The former is affected by `shift`/`set`, but the latter isn't:

```
$ cat test.sh 
echo "$#"
echo "${BASH_ARGV[@]}"
echo "$@"    
eval set -- foo bar
shift
echo "$#"
echo "${BASH_ARGV[@]}"
echo "$@"
$ bash test.sh x y z
3
z y x
x y z
1
z y x
bar
```

Comment: That's the one! Thanks! I need to better educate myself about bash variables and built-ins, I think.